# App: Bypass authentication for Open Graph facebook requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook app that can't be used before a user log in via Facebook (OAuth). Some pages (e.g. example.com/books/2) should be accessible for Open Graph requests (when they have been liked). Currently, Facebook isn't able to retrieve those pages since authentication is required (redirect). How can I determine if an incoming request is coming from Facebook or not? Or should I take another approch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an exception so that Facebook's crawler can reach the page, The user agent is currently `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`
(but the version number may increment someday)